# Using 1080p monitors with 4k monitor xrandr command

Tags: arch-linux, display, xrandr, high-dpi

I just got a 4k monitor to supplement my two 1080p monitors. However, I am having trouble getting the scaling working to everything looks good.

The monitors are physically set up like this:

```
 ____              ____
| DP1|____________| DP2|
|1080|     4k     |1080|
|    |_____DP3____|    |
|____|            |____|
```

Looking online, it seems like using xrandr along with --scale and --panning to get everything scaled and lined up correctly. However, I am trying to follow what I've seen and can't get it working.

The command I am trying is:

```
xrandr --dpi 163 --fb 11520x6480 --output DP-1 --scale 1.5x1.5 --pos 0x240 \
--rotate right --panning 2880x1620 --output DP-2 --scale 1.5x1.5 --pos 4920x260 \
--rotate left --panning 2880x1620+6720+0 --output DP-3 --mode 3840x2160`
```

When I execute the command, my 4k monitor looks fine, but the 2 1080p monitors seem to kind of mirror an area around the mouse cursor. With everything messed up like this, I am unable to open a terminal with the keyboard shortcut, so I have to reboot the system to get to a stable state.

I really appreciate any help with this.

Answer (score 0):

You asked 9 months ago, but if it's still a issue, you can try the commands below. I have a 4k + 1080p setup, and these commands handle it.

```
xrandr
output DP1
mode 1920x1080
pos 0x0
rate 60.00
transform 2,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,1
output DP2
mode 1920x1080
pos 0x0
rate 60.00
transform 2,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,1
post 0x4320
output DP3
pos 0x2160
primary
```

The key points are the transform and pos flag. I hope this helps.